# VSCodeの処理結果を出力からターミナルへ変更したい

Tags: java, vscode, kotlin

VSCodeの処理結果を"出力"から"ターミナル"へ変更したい

VSCodeの処理結果が、"出力"で日本語が文字化けするので、"ターミナル"で処理結果が見えるようにしたいです。
検索エンジンでうまく探せなかったので、教えて下さい。

ユーザ設定→設定→　この先が知りたいです。

Comment: どんな環境でどんなことをしているのでしょう？例えばこれらの記事との違いとかありますか？[Visual Studio CodeでJavaを書いて動かす【for Windows】](https://saktt-sw.com/write-java-on-vscode), [VSCodeでHello World!](https://qiita.com/u-devi/items/74caeaeec3a00cb5e557), [VS Codeをjava向けに設定してみた](https://info.acmatu.com/vscode_java.html), [Javaの実行環境の作り方](https://www.fit.ac.jp/~m-ishihara/Lectures/JavaProgramming1/howToSetupOnWin10new/howToSetup.html) こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に質問を改善してみてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ちなみに[XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701)なのでは？「VSCodeの処理結果が、"出力"で日本語が文字化けする」というのがおおもとの課題ではありませんか？そして「VSCodeの処理」とはどんなものなのかを追記した方が良いと思われます。

Comment: "出力"は文字通り"出力"で”ターミナル"は"ターミナル”なのでターミナルに何かコマンドを打ち込んでそれに対する出力が表示されることがあっても"ターミナル”に出力させることはできないと思います。Javaのバージョンを17にすると文字化けしない可能性があります。（私の記事ですが）詳しくはこちら https://zenn.dev/lamrongol/scraps/d4d9f081e5ec86

Comment: やっぱり JEP400（https://openjdk.org/jeps/400）なんですかねえ…。

Comment: 質問者さん、使っているOSは何ですか。VScodeは最新版ですか。Javaのバージョンはいくつですか。「出力」とはSystem.out.printとかですか、それとも何か別のものですか。いろいろ細かい情報を追加してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: ターミナル内で動いているのは普通のシェル（Windowsならcmd.exeかpowershell）なので普通にコマンドを叩けますが、ダイレクトにjavaコマンドで問題のプログラムを実行させたらどうなります？

Answer (score 0):

VS Codeの, 何らかの拡張機能(extension)を利用しているのでしょう
それを質問に記していないと分かりません

設定項目の一覧は

- アクティビティーバーの「拡張機能」から当該拡張を選ぶ

  - 出てきた画面のタブの中の「機能のコントリビューション」を選ぶと設定などの情報が得られる
- 「設定」内の「拡張機能」から該当する拡張機能を選ぶと その付近の設定が現れる

仮に [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)もしくはそれを元にした拡張だとするなら

`code-runner.runInTerminal` を `true` にすれば統合ターミナルに出力されるはず

他の拡張であれば, 質問にその旨記したほうがよいでしょう

Answer (score -1):

結論ですが、ターミナルで画面表示することができたので、解決しました。

尚、今回の質問の起点は、VSCodeでKotlinプログラム処理すると、日本語の文字化けして画面表示される事です。

尚、chcp65001、settings.jsonの書き換え等、Web上の参考記事を一通り試した結果、VSCode処理で日本語の文字化けが解決出来なかった事も、お伝えさせて頂きます。

この書き込みをもちまして、この質問をクローズとさせて頂きます。

皆さま、又、ご教示のほど、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 自己回答を付けるなら, **どのように**して解決に至ったかを記してください([編集](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/94988/edit)で編集可能)。「解決しました。」だけでは回答とは言えないので。また [質問が クローズ済み とは？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) など解釈違いがあるのでは？